# Adjust the size of the browser window when starting Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to predefine what size a Firefox browser window should have when starting? I would like to set it example 400px x 600px.
If yes, I assume it should be stored under a Firefox profile somehow?

Anyone having an idea?

Comment: The question should be moved to superuser.com probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Create a shortcut and append parameters at the end: `firefox.exe -width 400 -height 600`

Comment: This is not available now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no configuration setting for this with Firefox Quantum 64.  Nor is there a way to call firefox with width/height or geometry parameters.

However, the width & height are stored in a human-readable file, `xulstore.json`, in your profile.  So you can run a little program to change the size in that file before firefox opens.

For example, if you have a Linux system, a simple sed program with these 2 lines will set the size to 1000x1050 pixels:

```
 s/\(width[^0-9]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\11000/

 s/\(height[^0-9]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\11050/
```

I don't know anything about Windows or Mac scripting.

Answer (score 2):

An update to **jacub.g** answer.

Besides defining width and height you also need to provide a profile name

```
firefox -width 400 -height 600 -P default
```

You can also put some random name for the profile. Firefox will open a dialog window to create new profile if it does not find such.

```
firefox -width 400 -height 600 -P my_new_profile_name
```

Comment: It works, but I can't seem to use the same profile that would load without giving it a profile name. Using "default" brings in something else and opens pages I never visit, like MSN. Using "default-release" ignores the width-height settings. So now I'm half a step closer but not really there. (Why is this so difficult?)